# cheapest combination of items in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this csv file in python

```
SHOP_ID, COST, ITEM
1, 2.00, A
1, 1.25, B
1, 2.00, C
1, 1.00, D
1, 1.00, "A, B"
1, 1.50, "A, C"
1, 2.50, "A, D"
2, 3.00, A
2, 1.00, B
2, 1.20, C
2, 1.25, D
```

Ive read this file as a dataframe in python.

Now suppose I enter A,B,C,D as input and want to find the cheapest combination of ITEMS from my dataframe for this user input, then I should get :-

```
SHOP_ID=1
A,B(1.00)+A,C(1.50)+D(1.00) = 3.50
```

The user will get A,A,B,C,D i.e. an extra A, but as long as the total cost is minimum we dont care if the user gets extra item as freebie.

I dont know how to go about solving this problem. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
def build_shops(shop_text):
    shops = {}
    for item_info in shop_text:
        shop_id,cost,items = item_info.replace(' ', '').split(',')
        cost = float(cost)
        items = items.split('+')

        if shop_id not in shops:
            shops[shop_id] = {}
        shop_dict = shops[shop_id]

        for item in items:
            if item not in shop_dict:
                shop_dict[item] = []
            shop_dict[item].append([cost,items])
    return shops


def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    for item in items:
        if item not in shop:
            return [float('inf'), []]
    all_possible = []
    first_item = items[0]
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
        sub_set = [x for x in items if x not in combo]
        price_sub_set,solution = solve_one_shop(shop, sub_set)
        solution.append([price,combo])
        all_possible.append([price+price_sub_set, solution])

    cheapest = min(all_possible, key=(lambda x: x[0]))
    return cheapest


def solver(input_data, required_items):
    shops = build_shops(input_data)
    result_all_shops = []
    for shop_id,shop_info in shops.iteritems():
        (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
        if price != float('inf'):
            result_all_shops.append([shop_id, price, solution])
    if len(result_all_shops) == 0:
        print('No shop has all required items')
        return
    shop_id,total_price,solution = min(result_all_shops, key=(lambda x: x[1]))
    print('SHOP_ID=%s' % shop_id)
    sln_str = [','.join(items)+'(%0.2f)'%price for (price,items) in solution]
    sln_str = '+'.join(sln_str)
    print(sln_str + ' = %0.2f' % total_price)
```

Test:

```
input_data = [
    '1, 2.00, A',
    '1, 1.25, B',
    '1, 2.00, C',
    '1, 1.00, D',
    '1, 1.00, A+B',
    '1, 1.50, A+C',
    '1, 2.50, A+D',
    '2, 3.00, A',
    '2, 1.00, B',
    '2, 1.20, C',
    '2, 1.25, D',
]
required_items = ['A','B','C','D']
solver(input_data, required_items)
```

Output:

```
SHOP_ID=1
D(1.00)+A,C(1.50)+A,B(1.00) = 3.50
```

Please note that I use:

```
1, 1.00, A+B
```

instead of

```
1, 1.00, "A, B"
```

as the input format, just for a little easier formatting. You may modify function "build_shops" according to your format.

This solution basically do: pick item 'A', then compute the solution for set ('B','C','D'). To compute solution ('B','C','D'), it pick 'B' and compute set ('C','D'). It's a kind of divide-and-conquer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms). The key codes are:

```
    sub_set = [x for x in items if x not in combo]
    price_sub_set,solution = solve_one_shop(shop, sub_set)
```

To help understand the codes, I paste the output of "build_shops" here:

```
{'1': {'A': [(2.0, ['A']),
             (1.0, ['A', 'B']),
             (1.5, ['A', 'C']),
             (2.5, ['A', 'D'])],
       'B': [(1.25, ['B']), (1.0, ['A', 'B'])],
       'C': [(2.0, ['C']), (1.5, ['A', 'C'])],
       'D': [(1.0, ['D']), (2.5, ['A', 'D'])]},
 '2': {'A': [(3.0, ['A'])],
       'B': [(1.0, ['B'])],
       'C': [(1.2, ['C'])],
       'D': [(1.25, ['D'])]}}
```

This solution iterates all possible combinations, it's brute force. So won't be very efficient if the dataset if very large.

Test case 2:

```
input_data = [
    '1, 2.00, burger',
    '1, 1.25, tofu',
    '1, 2.00, tuna',
    '1, 1.00, salad',
    '1, 1.00, burger+tofu',
    '1, 1.50, burger+tuna',
    '1, 2.50, burger+salad',
    '2, 3.00, burger',
    '2, 1.00, tofu',
    '2, 1.20, tuna',
    '2, 1.25, salad',
]
required_items = ['burger','tofu','tuna','salad']
solver(input_data, required_items)
```

Output 2:

```
SHOP_ID=1
salad(1.00)+burger,tuna(1.50)+burger,tofu(1.00) = 3.50
```

Comment: Thanks zee, could you please brief a little on the code logic.

Comment: @sunita, I inserted a little explanation in the answer. You can check it at "This solution basically do......"

Comment: Hi zee, your code aint working . Im getting this : SHOP_ID=1
D(1.00)+A,C(1.50)+A,B(1.00) = 1.00

Comment: running your code in spyder LINE_NO:46  "    sln_str = [','.join(items)+'(%0.2f)'%price for (price,items) in solution]"  LIST COMPREHENSION REDEFINES PRICE FROM line 44.  LINE_NO:44 "shop_id,price,solution = min(result_all_shops, key=(lambda x: x[1]))"

Comment: @sunita, sorry that there's a bug, as you saw -- variable redefined. I have edited the answer a little to fix it (change 'price' to 'total_price')

Comment: Hi Zee, if instead of A,B,C,D im using burger,tofu,tuna,salad in the input data and required items then Im getting this error while running the code : - """ for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:  KeyError : 'tuna' """

Comment: @sunita, I tried "burger,tofu,tuna,salad". It worked fine here. You can compare with the test case 2, which I added. Did you type exactly same name in 'input_data' and 'required_items' ?

Comment: ###INPUT_DATA="1,2.00,burger
1,1.25,tofulog
1,1.50,A+CCC
2,1.20,CCC
2,1.25,D" ## REQUIRED=burger ## ERROR = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work.py", line 55, in <module>
    solver(shop_text,['burger'])
  File "work.py", line 43, in solver
    (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
  File "work.py", line 26, in solve_one_shop
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
KeyError: 'burger'

Comment: that's because 'burger' does not exist in Shop2. I added 3 lines in "solve_one_shop" to deal with this situation. Also updated "solver" a little, in case you want to search an item that doesn't exist in any shop. Please modify codes according to your own needs. The codes just show the thought, not a perfectly polished one working for all kind of input